# Need advice for merging two plists into an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, plist

Currently, I have a tableView which is loaded from the following array called `exerciseArray`:

```
if (exerciseArray == nil)
    {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSMutableArray *rootLevel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        self.exerciseArray = rootLevel;
        [rootLevel release];
    }
```

However, I want an option to let the user add their own data which will need to be displayed in this same table view.  I can either add that data to the original plist but I think it will be better to create a separate plist that will have the user added data.

So after the user adds data, the I will need to combine the 2 plist data next time.  Any idea how to implement this?  The user added data will need to match up with original plist structure which looks like:

[image]

The new plist should only have `ExerciseName` and `musclename`, but I need to merge the two somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user-defined Property List should be stored in a file somewhere in the *Documents* directory. Usually, for something like this, I would suggest creating a copy of the default Plist that ships with the app to the *Documents* directory, then modifying and loading this file as needed.  Copying the resource to the documents directory can be done as follows:

```
NSString * documentsPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString * docPlist = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:docPlist]) {
    NSString * resPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
    [[NSFileManager] defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:resPlist
                                             toPath:docPlist
                                              error:nil];
}
NSMutableArray * root = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:docPlist];
```

The above code simply finds the path to the plist in the documents directory, and checks if it exists. If it does not, it copies the *data.plist* resource over to the documents directory. Once this is done, it loads the root element into a mutable array, which you can then use and modify using the standard `addObject:` and `removeObject:` methods.

Finally, **to save any modified data**, simply write the `root` array back to the plist file as follows:

```
[root writeToFile:docPlist atomically:YES];
```

The only delemma with this is, while in the process of developing the app, you may wish to change or modify some data in the *data.plist* resource. In order for the app to copy this newly modified Property List to the *documents* directory, you will need to uninstall it completely from the iOS Simulator, then re-compile and run.

**Edit**: In order to **add an exercise** to an existing muscle, just do something like this:

```
// find the exercise dictionary
int muscleIndex = 0;
NSMutableDictionary * muscleDict = nil;
NSString * muscleName = @"Neck";
NSString * exerciseName = @"Nod your head a billion times";
// find the right muscle
for (int i = 0; i < [root count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary * muscle = [root objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([[muscle objectForKey:@"muscleName"] isEqualToString:muscleName]) {
        muscleIndex = i;
        muscleDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:muscle];
    }
}

NSMutableArray * exercises = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[muscleDict objectForKey:@"exercises"]];
[exercises addObject:exerciseName];
[muscleDict setObject:exercises forKey:@"exercises"];
[root replaceObjectAtIndex:muscleIndex withObject:muscleDict];
...
// save root here
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for the very detailed message. I'm going to do this.  One question though.  The user added data will be `exerciseName`.  I need to add this to the mutiple dictionary in the right place.  User will choose from menu which muscle it belongs to and I will need to add it to that muscle in the dictionary.  For example, user enters `Neck Pull Exercise` which belongs under `Neck` muscle, then in the pic above, I need to add it as `item 3` with `exerciseName.  How can I specify this?

Comment: Just loop through all of the items in root, and find the dictionary that has the correct `muscleName`. Then, create an `NSMutableArray` from the `exercises` of that dictionary, and add your new exercise. Then, replace the `exercises` array with your new NSMutableArray, and write the root array like normal.